# Why does NodaTime.LocalDate.MinIsoValue have a year "9999"

Tags: c#, nodatime

The static property `NodaTime.LocalDate.MinIsoValue` has the value `9999-01-01` whereas I'd have expected it to have the same value as `default(LocalDate)` which is `0001-01-01`. Is there a reason for this value or is it a bug?

I'm using NodaTime version 2.4.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formatting local date using pattern ["yy" or "yyyy" outputs years of era](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/localdate-patterns) not the year which is `-9998` in this case. [`LocalDate.MinIsoValue`](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDate.html#NodaTime_LocalDate_MinIsoValue) is from BCE era. The format you have used didn't include era in it. You can use `"g"` or `"gg"` in your custom format to include the era.

```
var def = default(LocalDate);
var min = LocalDate.MinIsoValue;
Console.WriteLine("def: " + def.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine("def with era: " + def.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd gg", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine("def.Year: " + def.Year);
Console.WriteLine("def.YearOfEra: " + def.YearOfEra);
Console.WriteLine("min: " + min.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine("min with era: " + min.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd gg", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine("min.Year: " + min.Year);
Console.WriteLine("min.YearOfEra: " + min.YearOfEra);
Console.WriteLine("min < def: " + (min < def));
```

> def: 0001-01-01
>   def with era: 0001-01-01 A.D.
>   def.Year: 1
>   def.YearOfEra: 1
>   min: 9999-01-01
>   min with era: 9999-01-01 B.C.
>   min.Year: -9998
>   min.YearOfEra: 9999
>   min < def: True